# Как посмотреть ошибку?

Tags: php, wordpress

Доброго времени друзья, при попытке залогиниться wp-login.php ничего не происходит, восстановить пароль нажимаешь, вводишь емэйл, тоже ничего не происходит, в обоих случаях якобы отправляется форма но инпуты просто становятся пустыми и я остаюсь на этой же wp-login.php, Где глядеть ошибку?

```
Remote Address:212.154.192.46:80
Request URL:http://vetef.kz/wp-login.php
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check
Host:vetef.kz
Referer:http://vetef.kz/wp-login.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 15 May 2014 09:10:52 GMT
Expires:Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx
Set-Cookie:wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; path=/
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.28
```

Answer (score 1):

В Гугл Хроме - Инструмент разработчика (F12) -- Вкладка Network  - посмотреть, куда уходит запрос, что уходит, что возвращается в ответ. Если залогивание с использованием js/jQuery - посмотреть ошибки во вкладке Console. Если с клиента всё уходит нормально, искать ошибки с серверной стороны.